# Impact of changing domain on Email Reputation

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

**Context :** 
Brand migration from example.com to example2.com

**Launch campaign :** 
Send a one-shot email on D-day to introduce the new brand to all the database (>500K subscribers)

**Requirements :** 
Use the new domain as a From Email address : contact@email.example2.com

**Action plan to meet the requirements:**

1. Use existing dedicated IP address (already warmed-up)
2. Purchase a new SAP sku and migrate only the domain
3. On D-Day, switch to the brand new domain
4. On D-Day, send the email to all the database

*Question 1 :*
Will the email reputation be affected by the domain migration ?

> The email reputation is mainly built on the IP address (IP reputation) but most ISPs are shifting to Domain reputation for filtering decisions.

*Question 2 :* 
If the email reputation will be affected, do you recommand a domain warmup campaign ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some ISP's that check the domain's reputation for filtering reasons like GMAIL. We are working with Return Path, an email deliverability expert integrated to our SFMC instance and they confirmed this.

So yeah, I think that a domain warmup is necessary. What I would recommend is doing the send on several days. Start by sending to your most engaged subscribers and so on..

Also, you should pay extra attention to GMAIL. What I usually do is send few hundreds emails the first days and check the delivrability, then act accordingly.

Comment: Domain Warmup and Reputation is almost as important as IP warmup. Subdomains are a different story as they all run off the root domains, so doing `email.domain.com` and `my.domain.com` will not need a warm up.  Domain is also important at Client level (e.g. Outlook) in email reputation as well. Changing domain means that anyone that had you as safe sender will no longer have it. Which means your emails, now coming from an unknown Domain, may wind up getting through server level, but get flagged on the email client. Which will lower interaction levels, which will lower IP/Domain Rep.

Comment: ^^ wanted to add some more to your answer as it is correct, rather than create a competing one. Another note is I would send multiple 'prep plan' emails from your old email to tell people to add the new domain to safe sender. Then slowly send to your audience from this new domain (most active first - segment X get from new domain, Y get from old) - increasing volume as you go. This way you can also monitor any hits to your rep or analytics as you go and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Gregory for adding the details. However, I'm quite surprised by the subdomains not needing a warmup. We have two subdomains, actu.xxxx.com and client.xxxx.com and we have been told by RP that we need to warmup the two of them. Maybe because we are using two different IP's?

Comment: yes, the IPs would be the reason the warmup is necessary. using the same subdomain on same IP would not need a warmup.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. This is becoming problematic because the email has to be sent to all the database on D-Day as it will be about 'announcing the new brand'. The root domain (of the new brand) already have a good WEB reputation according to https://www.talosintelligence.com/ . If I keep the same IP, is it really necessary to do a sub Domain warmup ?

Comment: subdomain no, completely new domain, yes.  e.g. `e.domain.com` to `m.domain.com` needs no warmup - but `domain.com` to `mynewdomain.com` does.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks!

Comment: how about domain.com to e.domain.com?  does this need warmup too? @Gortonington

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy - Going from main domain to subdomain does not require a warmup. It will still hit the same  issues around 'safe sender' and potentially falling into spam folder client-side. But comparatively, this is low level. You can likely address this by doing a follow up email to the non-openers from your current domain and tell them to add the new address to their 'whiteliest' (or mark as safe sender). This should then cover your bases.

Comment: I was looking things up to catch up on this and it appears that subdomains have become more like completely new domains now. So my comments are no longer valid. You will need to do a domain warmup on all new subdomains and new domains you send from.

Comment: Salesforce support has confirmed multiple times over the last week that change in the domain (of any kind) doesn't require IP warming (unless there's a change in the IP address)